# Update a TextView (UI thread) in a fragment background thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-fragments

I am trying to update a text view in with the value of I as it iterates through the for loop in a background thread. I have looked at the other answers and tried a few ways but it is not updating. Any advice on what I am doing wrong is appreciated.

This is my latest attempt:

```
        new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                // Start the detailed search of channels
                YoutubeChannelInfoConnector yc = new YoutubeChannelInfoConnector(getActivity());
                channelinfosearchResults = yc.search(chanelIdToSearchStringBuilder.toString());

                handler.post(new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){

                                // Add the new influencers to the database
                                for (int i = 0; i < youtubeCompleteArraylistOfChannelsSearchedInDetail.size(); i++){

                                    final int finalI = i;
                                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                            String addedInt = String.valueOf(finalI);
                                            newRecordsAddedToDatabaseTextView.setText(addedInt);
                                        }
                                    });

                                    Log.d("Database","record added " + i);
                                }

                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Database Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                loadingview.setVisibility(View.GONE);




                            } else {

                                // continue in the detailed search of channels
                                searchYoutubeChannels(channelsToAdd);
                            }
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ERROR: THE SEARCH RETURNED NO RESULTS!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

This may not make absolute sense because I had to cut so many lines out so it possible to read on stackoverflow.

Basically:

I have new thread, in that thread I have a handler with runnable which is running the following for loop:

```
   // Add the new influencers to the database
                                for (int i = 0; i < youtubeCompleteArraylistOfChannelsSearchedInDetail.size(); i++){

                                    final int finalI = i;
                                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        public void run() {
                                            String addedInt = String.valueOf(finalI);
                                            newRecordsAddedToDatabaseTextView.setText(addedInt);
                                        }
                                    });

                                    Log.d("Database","record added " + i);
                                }
```

I am using `getActivity.runonUI` because it is running in a fragment. Could that 
possibly be the reason the code is running but still not updating the TextView?

UPDATE:

I also tried the below code with a new handler but didn't work either:

```
final int finalI = i;
                                    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            String addedInt = String.valueOf(finalI);
                                            newRecordsAddedToDatabaseTextView.setText(addedInt);
                                        }
                                    });
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Don't put runOnUiThread inside the for loop. It is not a good practice

Comment: So how you update it then?

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this

```
 Handler handler=new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            // Add the new influencers to the database
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
                String addedInt = String.valueOf(i);
                Log.e("data",addedInt);
                view.setText(addedInt);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Database Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        }
    },2000);
```

Comment: You can use asynctask() to handle it and on onpostexecute() do that work

Comment: Thanks anyway.That doesn't work I want to update while the background thread is running not on postexecute at the end of the background task

Answer (score 0):

**Do something like this;**

```
Handler handler=new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                // Add the new influencers to the database
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
                    String addedInt = String.valueOf(i);
                    Log.e("data",addedInt);
                    view.setText(addedInt);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Database Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            }
        },2000);
```

Comment: then use Asynctask for background data update.
use same above method in Asynctask under  doInBackground(Void... params) method

Answer (score 0):

**Use this:**

```
public class Data extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Handler handler=new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                // Add the new influencers to the database
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
                    String addedInt = String.valueOf(i);
                    Log.e("data",addedInt);
                    view.setText(addedInt);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Database Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

            }
        },2000);

        return txt;
    }
}
```